# Qual a diferenças entre esses dois modos de salvar informações do formulário?

Tags: python, django

Estou aprendendo a usar os formulários do django e me foi apresentado duas maneiras de salvar informações de um formulário em um banco de dados. Testei as duas e ambas funcionam com validações, mas não entendi qual a diferença entre uma e outra.

A primeira utiliza funções herdadas da classe models.Model, usando a função "objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)" e passando como parâmetro os campos do formulário.

No exemplo abaixo, instancio a classe ProductForm que herda de 'forms.ModelForm' e utilizo a função 'cleaned_data' para passar como parâmetro.

```
def product_create_view(request):

    form = ProductForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            Product.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            form = ProductForm()

    data = {}
    data['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', data)
```

A segunda maneira invés de usar a funla 'objects.create(**dict)' utiliza o form.save() diretamente.

```
def product_create_view(request):

    form = ProductForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = ProductForm()

    data = {}
    data['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', data)
```

Resumidamente, eu gostaria de saber há diferenças entre usar form.save() e usar Product.objects.create(**dict).

Answer (score 0):

[Eu consegui uma resposta no stackoverflow em ingles que sanou a dúvida.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108840/what-are-the-differences-between-these-two-ways-of-saving-form-information/55109024#55109024) A tradução que fiz ficou assim.

Você somente pode usar o `form.save()` quando a classe do formulário herda de `ModelForm`. No geral essa é a maneira mais fácil de criar e atualizar dados de um  Model. Note que nesse casos `form.save()` retorna uma instância salva do objeto, assim você pode escrever `product = form.save()` e fazer outras operações com o objeto salvo.

Se você criar um formulário que herde somente da classe `Form`, esse formulário não terá link com nenhum model específico e logo não será possível salvar com `form.save()`. Deste modo você terá que criar um objeto usando como parâmetros os dados do formulário com a função `cleaned_data`. Você terá que definir todos os campos do formulário com os mesmos nomes dos campos do `Model`, o que é bem mais trabalhoso do que usar o `ModelForm`, onde você pode só listar os parâmetros do Model.

No final não há diferença nos resultados, mas geralmente é preferível usar form.save() herdando de ModelForm, pois é mais legível e mais simples de entender o que está sendo feito.

Comment: Sua resposta não está errada mas não é suficiente, ha muitas situacoes em que `form.save()` não é adequada, exemplos: Imagine que de acordo com a escolha do usuário, antes persistir os dados vc tenha que realizar um calculo ou consultar uma api para atualizar um campo não presente no form.